# Swagger UI configuration via Apache CXF's Swagger2Feature

Tags: cxf, swagger-ui

I use the Swagger2Feature in Apache CXF to provide Swagger documentation for our API. Swagger UI is provided as a Maven dependency via WebJars.

I would like to configure some Swagger UI properties (as documented [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md)), for example validatiorUrl. Is this possible to accomplish when using the combination of WebJars / CXF? I can't find a way to configure these settings "at runtime".

I'm using CXF 3.2.1 and Swagger UI 3.17.1.

Comment: Good idea, could you please open an issue for it? https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CXF

I suggest that we implement that for the new OpenApiFeature instead of the old Swagger2Feature, see also: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/openapifeature.html

Comment: @DennisKieselhorst - done, please see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-7826.